# I wish you a nice flight!

Tags: word-choice

A friend is going abroad. Does the phrase **I wish you a nice flight** suit for wishing her a pleasant flight? Doesn't it sound too formal, as if it is said by airline personnel to the passengers?

Yes, I know that "Have a good/nice flight" is obvious here, but is it possible to say "I wish you a nice flight"?

Thanks.

Comment: Sure. It is not too formal at all. It sounds cheerful and sincere.

Comment: I wish you good luck with this question.

Comment: I personally can't imagine a native English speaker saying this.

Comment: You might use _wish_ here if you are not just speaking (or writing) on your own behalf. So, for instance, in an email from a travel service you might see "We wish you a nice flight". But your sentence "I wish you a nice flight" definitely sounds a bit foreign.

Comment: What @Martin, TonyK said (the *definitely sounds a bit foreign* bit, at least). For that reason I think this question belongs on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I would always use the French *bon voyage* - there being no exact English equivalent, nor one that meets all the requirements of such a sentiment.

Comment: @WS2 Isn't "Have a nice trip / Nice trip" close enough to bon voyage?

Comment: @Rathony You pays your money, you takes your choice.

Comment: Sounds about as sincere to me as American cashiers' standard "Have a good day!" as you carry your groceries away.

Comment: @WS2 - I personally favor *Bon voyage* too; but there is also *Safe travels* for those times when the other person seems unlikely to understand.

Comment: @aparente001 I never wish someone a *safe flight*. There can be nothing more likely to induce fear of flying than perpetually being wished "a safe flight". The place where most people die is in bed - but how often do you say "have a safe sleep"?

Comment: @WS2 - Well, one of my children has OCD, and when he freaked out because his other parent was traveling to Europe on a *plane* (shudder!), he was able to calm down by looking up the statistics on airplane safety.  However, I personally hate flying because they treat you like garbage these days.... At any rate, I suggested "safe travels", not "safe flight."  Btw, my favorite way to say good night in English is "Good night, sleep tight, don't let the bedbugs bite."  (I have actually experienced bedbugs, and they can really drive you nuts!  But the phrase brings pleasant childhood memories.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not a native English speaker I suggest you avoid using the word 'nice'. It is very weak as a simple adjective, and only works in certain contexts. In the present example I would suggest "pleasant". However if you are using British English the phrase is "Bon voyage".

A native speaker would probably say something like "have a good flight" or — being more honest — "hope your flight isn't too hellish", as air travel (at least in economy) is never, in my experience, pleasant.